# How to add Shift-Click option to button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Python, and especially GUI Python, and am trying to figure out how to add two functions to my button.

For example, I want user to be able to:
click on button normally and button to execute function one
shift-click on button and button to execute function number two.

I am using tkinter for GUI.

Code for button:

Any help is appreciated.

```
b1 = Button(window, text = "Import", width = 12, command = functionOne)
b1.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this - Instead of setting the button's `command` keyword argument, just bind different events captured by the button to different functions. Here's some more info about [events and binding events](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python/0596001886_pythonian-chp-16-sect-9.html).

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Test")
        self.geometry("128x32")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Try Me")
        self.button.pack()

        self.button.bind("<Button-1>", self.normal_click)
        self.button.bind("<Shift-Button-1>", self.shift_click)

    def normal_click(self, event):
        print("Normal Click")

    def shift_click(self, event):
        print("Shift Click")


def main():

    application = Application()
    application.mainloop()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```