# tkinter check if Shift is down when Button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, onclick

I have a `tk.Button(..., command=_on_button_click)`.
Once it is clicked, I want to know whether the Shift key is currently held down.

But the `_on_button_click` is called without any event object or similar for me to check it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Shift-Click option to button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646497/how-to-add-shift-click-option-to-button)

Comment: You cannot set a shift click `command` however you can do this with a `bind`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a button named `button` and a handler named `shift_click`, you can use the `bind` method:

`button.bind("<Shift-Button-1>", shift_click)`

Of course, you will probably also want one without shift click:

`button.bind("<Button-1>", not_shift_click)`

Comment: Looks good, but it seems to miss clicks not using the mouse. e.g using Enter. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @user972014 I have not tested, but possibly drop the second bind and re-add the command param? I am not sure if this will overwrite the shift button thing, or activate both at the same time. Maybe you could just bind the enter key as well. As a matter of opinion, tk is pretty poorly thought out.